# quartz schedular triggers histoy need save in data base after firing

Tags: quartz-scheduler

i am using CronTriggerBean and SimpleTriggerBean quartz schedulers for execute the triggers.After executing the triggers permanently not save the details about triggers. Before execute the triggers data is stored after execute it is deleted what is the problem. For that i am using code.

```
 <prop   key="org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.class">org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin</prop>    
    <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.triggerFiredMessage">Trigger {1}.{0} fired job {6}.{5} at: {4, date, HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy}</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.triggerCompleteMessage">Trigger {1}.{0} completed firing job {6}.{5} at {4, date, HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy} with resulting trigger instruction code: {9}</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.triggerMisfiredMessage">Trigger [{1}.{0}] misfired job [{6}.{5}]. Should have fired at: {3, date, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.class">org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobToBeFiredMessage">Job [{1}.{0}] to be fired by trigger [{4}.{3}], re-fire: {7}</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobSuccessMessage">Job {1}.{0} fired at: {2, date, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} result=OK</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobFailedMessage">Job {1}.{0} fired at: {2, date, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} result=ERROR</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobWasVetoedMessage">Job [{1}.{0}] was vetoed. It was to be fired by trigger [{4}.{3}] at: {2, date, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}</prop>
```

Comment: Hari, did you find answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new pluginHistoty which does save in db and use it instead of org.quartz.plugins.history.

```
LoggingInDbTriggerHistoryPlugin : ISchedulerPlugin, ITriggerListener
...

public virtualvoid TriggerComplete(..){
   //save in db
}
```